# Where we might need pre-commit and pre-push hooks together to lint our code

Tags: git, github, gitlab, githooks, pre-commit-hook

Assuming we have linter in our project. I have a pre-commit hook which will lint my project and if lint passes with no error it will commit. I want to setup a pre-push hook to lint my project on push. But I don't see the point of doing it on push since the code will be already linted on commit. So, Can anyone point me a scenario where a pre-push lint would be necessary with already having a pre-commit link?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `pre-commit` hook, then there's no need for a `pre-push` hook as well.  Both will cover the same set of commits in normal usage.  Both can also be bypassed with `--no-verify`, so neither one is appropriate as an access control.  A `pre-commit` hook can nevertheless be a useful tool for developers who with to use one.

If you want to enforce linting on your codebase, you should use a check in your CI system, which users cannot modify.  That leaves the `pre-commit` hook for users who find it useful, and more advanced users, who may create many throwaway commits they don't want to lint, can skip it and rely on CI.

Answer (score 2):

If they're the same set of checks, I agree that there's no reason to have both `pre-commit` and `pre-push`

however, if they are different checks (which I usually suggest keeping only the fastest checks in `pre-commit` and the slower checks in `pre-push`) then there's reason to use both of the hooks.

An example might be something fast like a syntax check in `pre-commit` and a run of unit tests in `pre-push`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you do linting your code on both hooks. Assuming your branch uses the pre-comit hook and is linted. And there is another branch which is not linted. Then you rebase your branch from the unlimited branch and wanted to push. At this time the pre-push hook will prevent you from pushing unless you fix those lint issues. The same goes for merging unlinted branch to your branch and tries to push.